# adobe flash show/hide different movieclips in different frames with one button Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jquery-animate, adobe

I created a button to a layer and I am trying to show movieclip com7 in frame 1 when I click the button named quest. Then, I would like to show a different movieclip com9 in frame 2. I put the movieclips in another layer each one in frames1 and 2.

In frame1 the code is:

```
quest.visible=true;
com7.visible=false;
quest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q7_clicked);
function q7_clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if  (com7.visible==false) 
    {com7.visible=true
    }
    else
    {
    com7.visible=false;
    }
    }
```

in frame 2:

```
quest.visible=true;

com9.visible=false;
quest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q9_clicked);

function q9_clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    if  (com9.visible==false) 
    {com9.visible=true
    }
    else
    {
    com9.visible=false;
    }
    }
```

Flash creates the swf without errors but when I click the button in frame2 there is a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at meli_fla::MainTimeline/q7_clicked()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at meli_fla::MainTimeline/q9_clicked()
```

Comment: If means that at the time you click the button, there is no `com9`.   Perhaps you've moved to a frame where that asset is not present by the time the button is clicked?

Comment: ok.right. com7 is only at frame 1.when i click at frame 2  for com9 ,i think that the system "reads" the code for com7 too. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you add event listeners on the timeline, those listeners do not automatically go away when you change frames (no code does).

So on frame 1, you just have the one listener and it probably works fine.
On frame 2, you create a new listener, but the one from before on frame 1 is also still hanging around, so when you click the `quest` button, it actually calls `q7_clicked` and `q9_clicked`.  No matter what frame you are one, at this point clicking the button you added the listeners to will always call both functions.

Your error, is because the objects you're referencing (`com9`, `com7`) are likely not around on both frames you are visiting (confirmed from you comments on the question).

To remedy the problem, you need to remove the appropriate event listener when you move to a new frame.

So, wherever in your code you do `nextFrame();` or `gotoAndStop(2);` or however you move the user to another frame, at that time remove the listener on the button:

```
quest.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q7_clicked);
gotoAndStop(2);
```

Or, if returning to frame 1:

```
quest.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, q9_clicked);
gotoAndStop(1);
```

Comment: ok thanks! it works. but is there a way to do this for all the functions reffered to an object like quest.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, "all the functions"); ?

Comment: Not really.  You can use a for/loop to it  (either by storing all the functions in an array or by referencing the function dynamically.  `for(var i:int=1;i<=9;i++){ quest.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["q" + i + "_clicked]); }`